# c programming - invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘record_s*

Tags: c, error-handling, directory-listing

I get a code from StackOverflow. I compile my code in raspbian under GCC. the extension of my file is cpp. when I compile my code I get the following error: I mentioned that if any useful code for listing all files and directory in the given path and given depth in the fastest and most right way, I will be appreciated. I think that this code can do indexing files and folders in the right and fast way. please when you do answer to this question give the full code and compile command for raspbian.

```
 error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘record_s* {aka main(int, const char**)::record_s*}’ [-fpermissive]
   pos = malloc(sizeof(*pos) + strlen(argv[1]) + 2);
         ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cpp_list_directory.cpp:125:55: error: ‘struct dirent’ has no member named ‘d_namlen’; did you mean ‘d_name’?
       item = malloc(sizeof(*item) + pos->len + entry->d_namlen + 2);
                                                       ^~~~~~~~
cpp_list_directory.cpp:127:37: error: ‘struct dirent’ has no member named ‘d_namlen’; did you mean ‘d_name’?
       item->len = pos->len + entry->d_namlen;
                                     ^~~~~~~~
cpp_list_directory.cpp:129:59: error: ‘struct dirent’ has no member named ‘d_namlen’; did you mean ‘d_name’?
       memcpy(item->name + pos->len, entry->d_name, entry->d_namlen);
```

my code is :

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  /* print use instruction unless a folder name was given */
  if (argc < 2)
    fprintf(stderr,
            "\nuse:\n"
            "    %s <directory>\n"
            "for example:\n"
            "    %s ./\n\n",
            argv[0], argv[0]),
        exit(0);

  /*************** a small linked list macro implementation ***************/

  typedef struct list_s {
    struct list_s *next;
    struct list_s *prev;
  } list_s;

#define LIST_INIT(name)                                                        \
  { .next = &name, .prev = &name }

#define LIST_PUSH(dest, node)                                                  \
  do {                                                                         \
    (node)->next = (dest)->next;                                               \
    (node)->prev = (dest);                                                     \
    (node)->next->prev = (node);                                               \
    (dest)->next = (node);                                                     \
  } while (0);

#define LIST_POP(list, var)                                                    \
  if ((list)->next == (list)) {                                                \
    var = NULL;                                                                \
  } else {                                                                     \
    var = (list)->next;                                                        \
    (list)->next = var->next;                                                  \
    var->next->prev = var->prev;                                               \
  }

  /*************** a record (file / folder) item type ***************/

  typedef struct record_s {
    /* this is a flat processing queue. */
    list_s queue;
    /* this will list all queued and processed folders (cyclic protection) */
    list_s folders;
    /* this will list all the completed items (siblings and such) */
    list_s list;
    /* unique ID */
    ino_t ino;
    /* name length */
    size_t len;
    /* name string */
    char name[];
  } record_s;

/* take a list_s pointer and convert it to the record_s pointer */
#define NODE2RECORD(node, list_name)                                           \
  ((record_s *)(((uintptr_t)(node)) -                                          \
                ((uintptr_t) & ((record_s *)0)->list_name)))

/* initializes a new record */
#define RECORD_INIT(name)                                                      \
  (record_s){.queue = LIST_INIT((name).queue),                                 \
             .folders = LIST_INIT((name).folders),                             \
             .list = LIST_INIT((name).list)}

  /*************** the actual code ***************/

  record_s records = RECORD_INIT(records);
  record_s *pos, *item;
  list_s *tmp;
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *entry;

  /* initialize the root folder record and add it to the queue */
  pos = malloc(sizeof(*pos) + strlen(argv[1]) + 2);
  *pos = RECORD_INIT(*pos);
  pos->len = strlen(argv[1]);
  memcpy(pos->name, argv[1], pos->len);
  if (pos->name[pos->len - 1] != '/')
    pos->name[pos->len++] = '/';
  pos->name[pos->len] = 0;
  /* push to queue, but also push to list (first item processed) */
  LIST_PUSH(&records.queue, &pos->queue);
  LIST_PUSH(&records.list, &pos->list);

  /* as long as the queue has items to be processed, do so */
  while (records.queue.next != &records.queue) {
    /* pop queued item */
    LIST_POP(&records.queue, tmp);
    /* collect record to process */
    pos = NODE2RECORD(tmp, queue);
    /* add record to the processed folder list */
    LIST_PUSH(&records.folders, &pos->folders);

    /* process the folder and add all folder data to current list */
    dir = opendir(pos->name);
    if (!dir)
      continue;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {

      /* create new item, copying it's path data and unique ID */
      item = malloc(sizeof(*item) + pos->len + entry->d_namlen + 2);
      *item = RECORD_INIT(*item);
      item->len = pos->len + entry->d_namlen;
      memcpy(item->name, pos->name, pos->len);
      memcpy(item->name + pos->len, entry->d_name, entry->d_namlen);
      item->name[item->len] = 0;
      item->ino = entry->d_ino;
      /* add item to the list, right after the `pos` item */
      LIST_PUSH(&pos->list, &item->list);

      /* unless it's a folder, we're done. */
      if (entry->d_type != DT_DIR)
        continue;

      /* test for '.' and '..' */
      if (entry->d_name[0] == '.' &&
          (entry->d_name[1] == 0 ||
           (entry->d_name[1] == '.' && entry->d_name[2] == 0)))
        continue;

      /* add folder marker */
      item->name[item->len++] = '/';
      item->name[item->len] = 0;

      /* test for cyclic processing */
      list_s *t = records.folders.next;
      while (t != &records.folders) {
        if (NODE2RECORD(t, folders)->ino == item->ino) {
          /* we already processed this folder! */
          break; /* this breaks from the small loop... */
        }
        t = t->next;
      }
      if (t != &records.folders)
        continue; /* if we broke from the small loop, entry is done */

      /* item is a new folder, add to queue */
      LIST_PUSH(&records.queue, &item->queue);
    }
    closedir(dir);
  }

  /*************** Printing the results and cleaning up ***************/
  while (records.list.next != &records.list) {
    /* pop list item */
    LIST_POP(&records.list, tmp);
    /* collect record to process */
    pos = NODE2RECORD(tmp, list);
    /* prepare for next iteration */
    LIST_POP(&records.list, tmp);
    fwrite(pos->name, pos->len, 1, stderr);
    fwrite("\n", 1, 1, stderr);
    free(pos);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

i compile the code in gcc with the following command :

```
g++ -Wall cpp_list_directory.cpp -o cpp_list_directory
```

Comment: This code looks like C code (and you tagged [tag:c]). Did you name the file with suffix `cpp`? It seems your gcc thinks it shall compile as C++. In C, `void*` is compatible to any other pointer type. Hence, it's not usual to cast return of `malloc()`. (It's even considered as bad style.) However, a C++ compiler is more restrictive and doesn't like that. May be, I also should mention that gcc can both - C and C++. It guesses by suffix which language intended (or is determined by a resp. command line option which you probably didn't give).

Comment: if the file extension is `.cpp` then you are using a c++ compiler to compile c++ code.... see the comment above about the c++ guidelines to convert pointers, as you are making several mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

the compiler is telling you that (on your platform) the field: `d_namelen` is not implemented in `struct dirent`

here is the definition of `struct dirent`

```
struct dirent {
    long d_ino;
    off_t d_off;
    unsigned short d_reclen;
    char d_name[1];
};
```

However your code can obtain the length of the file name via:

```
DIR *directoryEntry;
size_t length = strlen( directoryEntry->d_name );
```

The messages about `void*`, etc are due to your working with C++.  (so why the `c` tag on the question rather than `c++`

Comment: unfortunatelly your answer wont work for me.  can you please help me with bring full correct code ?

Comment: Per the error messages, the target file is a C++ file, not a C file.  The programming language C++ is MUCH MORE PICKY about casting, etc

Comment: Why is my answer not working for you?  please clarify